# Replaced water filter now very low pressure

Tags: refrigerator, water-pressure, filter

Recently replaced my Samsung water filter with new filter. Water was coming out at regular speed before. Now it is extremely slow.

Here is what I have tried:

- check if water coming into refrigerator had issues. Nothing out of ordinary
- run filter under water to remove air bubbles. Did that. No change
- check if I have the correct filter. I do.
- run the water without a filter in. Exact same speed.

Not sure what to do. I hate calling a refrigerator person because they always say it’s not a fridge issue, and when I call a plumber they say it’s not a plu

Comment: Given your description I can only think of three possible causes: (1) If the old filter was in a long time, when you removed it a piece of the filter o ring may have broken away and is partially clogging the line. (2) A calcifium deposit from hard water may have broken away with the same result. (3) If you moved the fridge in this process you may have kinked the water supply line on the back.

Comment: 4: Check to make sure the valve you closed to replace the filter has been fully opened again.

Comment: a piece of crud may have come loose while there was no pressure in the line, resulting in a clog between filter and spout. Flush it backwards with water, or at least try blowing into the spout while the filter is removed to unjam the detritus.

Comment: @keshlam - Good addition. Even though Samsung doesn't require shutting off the supply valve to change the filter some people do anyway as a precaution.